# Cell value yes/no based on autoshape button yes/no value

Tags: vba, excel

I have 3 autoshape buttons(BTN1;BTN2;BTN3), on click each will toggle Yes, No, Maybe.

If 1 or more of the buttons is toggled No, then cell A1 value is No, otherwise cell value is Yes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `=and(ceiling(BTN1),ceiling(BTN2),ceiling(BTN3))` with rounding for the maybes, that way a single `No` will result in zero.

Comment: Ok interesting but I was looking in  achieving this with VBA. I have been fiddling with this code but it only runs manually. Any suggestions appreciated. 'Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Worksheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Btn1", "Btn2", "Btn3")).TextFrame.Characters.Text = "No" Then
Range("A1").Value = "No"
Else: Range("A1").Value = "Yes"
End Sub'

Comment: Sorry, assumed you were asking about excel only from your question. I'm no expert in VGA but you should define your macro (checking it does what you need -- you can use `and`, etc in VGA). Then right click on the autoshape button and assign the macro `Private Sub Worksheet_Change` to run on click...

Comment: Yes I am using 'Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)' i can tell its gross wired code but that's all i can figure out for now. Well i'll reinforce my research tomorrow, GMT rules.

Answer (score 0):

I have attempted to modify below code to suit my need but still, not quite there, the original code will copy the 'shape.textframe.text' 'value' to a 'cell' but I need the 'value to be `Yes' if 'shape value is Maybe'.

> ```
> Sub TextBox()
>     Dim txBox As Shape
>     Set txBox = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Btn1")
>     With Range("A1").Value = txBox.TextFrame.Characters.Text
>     If txBox.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "N/A" Then Range("A1").Value = "Yes"
>     End With
>     End Sub
> ```